# How to Rebuild and Run android project from command line

Tags: android, command-line, build, installation

I want create same process that android studio run in background through command line

```
like first clean project -> build project -> Run Project  all through command line
```

(may be duplicate but not found all process in one answer)
what i try till now is

```
path upto project to run command
   D:\ProjectWorkSpace\testDevelopmentV3_12_26
        gradlew clean        -   To clean project 
        gradlew.bat assembleRelease  -   To Build project 

    D:\MySDKBackUp\sdk\platform-tools   
        adb push D:\ProjectWorkSpace\testDevelopmentV3_12_26\----\build\outputs\apk\----debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.---.---
        adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.----.---"
        adb shell am start -n "com.---.---/com.---.---.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 
above code to  upload apk on device -> install apk -> run apk
```

But problem is above command not taking updated data (new changes made is not reflected in apk ) so i want all command that hit when we press shift+F10 (Run) in android studio so that i can run it from  command prompt

For those who want flow for run in

```
path upto project to run command
       D:\ProjectWorkSpace\testDevelopmentV3_12_26
            gradlew installDebug


    path upto your sdk/platform tools           
            D:\MySDKBackUp\sdk\platform-tools   
                adb push D:\ProjectWorkSpace\testDevelopmentV3_12_26\----\build\outputs\apk\----debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.---.---
                adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.----.---"
                adb shell am start -n "com.---.---/com.---.---.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute all the build tasks available to your Android project using the Gradle wrapper command line tool. It's available as a batch file for Windows (gradlew.bat) and a shell script for Linux and Mac (gradlew.sh), and it's accessible from the root of each project you create with Android Studio.

You want same as `Shift+F10` so use `gradlew installDebug` instead `gradlew assembleDebug`. It will build and install apk in connected adb device.

Thank and refer [**Build Your App from the Command Line**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html) for more help.

Thanks to above link!

Answer (score 4):

You can execute the commands from the root of your android project.

For cleaning the project, run `./gradlew clean`.
After cleaning, for building the project, run `./gradlew build`.

For installation, run `./gradlew installDebug`.

Also you can merge these steps in a single line as follows:
`./gradlew clean build installDebug`.